# How to pass HTTPBody in urlrequest swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

[image: qu]

How to pass HTTPBody like this content type in urlrequest

below is the code which i tried from postman code -

```
  var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

    let parameters = "code=httagtsgdgtdfsg&client_secret=agsfstf&Grant_type=authorization_code"
    let postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "HTTPMethod"
    request.httpBody = postData
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in 
      guard let data = data else {
        print(String(describing: error))
        return
      }
      print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
      semaphore.signal()
    }
    task.resume()
    semaphore.wait()
```

Comment: Ask POSTMAN (on the right) to generate Swift code.

Comment: i used it but getting bad request(400), so

Comment: And what's the generated code?

Comment: added codefrom postman

Comment: You could use a swift package if you want. https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/ServiceManager

Comment: That's bad code (POSTMAN doesn't generate good code, but working one), but that's how it's supposed to be done. If you have a 400, are you sure it's working on Postman?

Comment: yes it is working in postman

Answer (score 0):

What's this?

```
request.httpMethod = "HTTPMethod"
```

It should be

```
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```